# Search/Filter operator for user rep

Tags: feature-request, search, filtering

This may have been asked before, but recently just thought of a new potential search operator for user reputation.

Suppose the following is entered:

`[sql] votes:0 question answers:0`

I would expect it to show `sql` tagged questions with 0 votes and 0 answers.

Then if you want to further rule out user(s) say with at least a rep score of 5, add `user_rep:5` or something to that effect. The use case for this addition might allow for someone to further refine the results so that they don't have to wonder if this poster frequently posts questions and does not accept them.

Comment: Why would you want to filter questions by user rep? SO is all about content, not users. Good/great questions can be asked by any user, regardless of their reputation.

Comment: Yes, good point. Though the potential answerer would be able to further refine the result and save some research as to whether the poster just posts a lot of questions and never accepted any, lets them linger w/o acceptance, etc.

Comment: "The use case for this addition might allow for someone to further refine the results so that they don't have to wonder if this poster frequently posts questions and does not accept them." Filtering by rep seems to be almost entirely useless for this effect. Just about *any* rep gain, say a question upvote, would bypass the filter.

Comment: Besides, users are not required to accept an answer to any question. If you are answering a question for the purpose of having it accepted, you are doing it wrong.

Answer (score 9):

Searching by the user's reputation is a terrible idea. Antithetical to the model of Stack Overflow. If you are searching for *content*, the reputation of who posted it does not really matter. Moreover, the reputation can easily change, so your query becomes quite useless.

However, the justification given to "research" users is exceptionally weak.

- If you really want to check a user's post history, you should [check the user's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11472002/etch-45?tab=questions) [post history](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A11472002+is%3Aq). A reputation filter does not do that, nor does it help in any way to narrow down a particular user.
- You should not be watching out for "acceptance rates" anyway. You certainly are free to do so yourself, but trying to justify a feature by citing acceptance rates is extraordinary bad form. [The acceptance statistics *were* public in the past but then removed as it led to abuse.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136951/lets-stop-displaying-a-users-accept-rate)

Comment: That could be an argument for not showing the reputation points, badges, etc. on posts, but just an anonymous link to the user profile. E.g., behind the link text *"Answered 3 hours ago"*. The "show off" part of the original design could be changed.